# How to open url and get access token entirely inside app, without safari?

Tags: ios, oauth, access-token, afnetworking-2

How do you open a URL and get an access token inside your app without using safari?

Instead of this, `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:authURL];`, what should I do?

EDIT:
What if I just used the authentication URL in an GET call? Would that work?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried CURL?

With in application? Try libCURL.